# How to display items from different types in a Table in Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

**Desired Result :**

[image]

I have a list of objects that contains the Title of every section in the menu and in this list I have the list of images and other information

I've been strugeling on how to display them properly

my xaml :

```
<ContentPage.Content>
    <TableView Intent="Form">
        <TableRoot>
            <TableSection Title="Getting Started">
                <ViewCell>
                    <Grid VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" Padding = "20, 0" >
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />

                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" ></RowDefinition>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" ></RowDefinition>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <StackLayout Grid.Row="0" x:Name="Titre" Orientation="Horizontal">

                        </StackLayout>
                        <ScrollView Grid.Row="1">
                            <StackLayout
                                Padding="0"
                                x:Name="Image">
                            </StackLayout>
                        </ScrollView>
                    </Grid>
                </ViewCell>
            </TableSection>

        </TableRoot>
    </TableView>

</ContentPage.Content>
```

The C# Method :

```
 private void PopulateProductsLists(List<PlanDefinition> listArticles)
        {


            for (var i = 0; i < listArticles.Count; i++)
                {
                    //Display Title 
                 Titre.Children.Add((new Label { Text = listArticles[i].Name, Style = Device.Styles.TitleStyle, FontAttributes = FontAttributes.Bold, TextColor = Color.White }));

                //Display Images from  listArticles[i].ArticlesAvailable
                for (int j= 0; j < listArticles[i].ArticlesAvailable.Count; j++)
                    {

                        listArticles[i].ArticlesAvailable[j].ImageProduit = "https://fit-plans.com/" + listArticles[i].ArticlesAvailable[j].UrlSmallImage;

                        Image image = new Image();
                        image.Source = ImageSource.FromUri(new Uri(listArticles[i].ArticlesAvailable[j].ImageProduit));


                        Image.Children.Add(image);


                }
```

What I am droing wrong?

Comment: What does it display now

Comment: Can you please describe or show with an image where and how you fail, what does not satisfy you with your code.

Comment: It was displaying a disaster , that's why , but I have managed to found the issue , I will post an answer very soon once I figure out how to place maximum 2 images next to each other than go to a new line

Comment: If you can run Xamarin forms 3.0, you could try the new `FlexLayout` control. Sadly, this doesn't have a bindable `ItemsCollection`, so you would need to iterate through your collection and manually add controls to the `Children` collection, but it functions as a `WrapGrid`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all here were my mistakes :

**1- Not using a scrollable view**

**2- Using different stack layouts**

The remedy to my issue :

```
<!----Scrollable view MUST be used otherwide data simply won't appear  --->
    <ScrollView
                Grid.Column="0"
                Grid.Row="1">
                <Grid 
                    RowSpacing="3"   
                    x:Name="MyGrid"
                    ClassId="myGrid">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />       
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <StackLayout VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                                 HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                        x:Name="ProduitsLayout">
                       <!----Products will be displayed here --->
                    </StackLayout>
                </Grid>
            </ScrollView>
```

**And in the code behind :**

```
     private void PopulateProductsLists(List<PlanDefinition> listArticles)
            {
                int labelIndex = 0;
                int count = 0;
                for (var i = 0; i < listArticles.Count; i++)
                {
                   //Calling a view to display data
                    item = new PlanOrderTemplate();             

                    var lastHeight = "100";
                    var y = 0;
                    int column = 1;
                    var productTapGestureRecognizer = new TapGestureRecognizer();

                //Add label in the stack layout
                    ProduitsLayout.Children.Add((new Label
                    {
                        Text = listArticles[i].Name,
                        Style = Device.Styles.TitleStyle,
                        FontAttributes = FontAttributes.Bold,
                        TextColor = Color.Black
                    }));


                    for (int j = 0; j < listArticles[i].ArticlesAvailable.Count; j++)
                    {

                        productTapGestureRecognizer.Tapped += OnProductTapped;

                        item = new PlanOrderTemplate();

                        listArticles[i].ArticlesAvailable[j].ThumbnailHeight = lastHeight;
                       //Applying binding to the view in order to display data
                            item.BindingContext = listArticles[i].ArticlesAvailable[j];
                            item.GestureRecognizers.Add(productTapGestureRecognizer);

        //This is mandatory you need to call the add the view page to the stack layout
                            ProduitsLayout.Children.Add(item);
    }
    }
}
```

Now as for the view page I'm talking about : **ProduitsLayout.xaml**

Configure the image I want to load with a stepper

```
<StackLayout Orientation="Vertical"

        Spacing="1">

        <ffimageloading:CachedImage 
            FadeAnimationEnabled="true" 
            Source="{Binding ImageProduit}" 
            HeightRequest="{Binding ThumbnailHeight}" 
            Aspect="AspectFill"/>

        <Label x:Name="lbldisp"  Text="1" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center"></Label>
        <Stepper Minimum="0" Maximum="10" Increment="1" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" ValueChanged="OnValueChanged" />



</StackLayout>
```